# How to provide needed dependencies for @WebMvcTest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, mockito

My WebMvcTest starts Spring Security, I mean my config class.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    UserService userService;
  @Autowired
public SecurityConfig(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

    @Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    daoProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    return daoProvider;
// random settings
}
```

But it has a dependency from UserService. So my test fails with fails to load Application Context exception, userService bean is not found ( because it's marked with `@Service` and `@WebMvcTest` starts only `@Controller`.

How to satisfy the dependency? Is `@MockBean` my only option? I don't want to turn off security as I need security context in my tests ( want to check if user is properly injected ( as I use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` in my Controller )).

Here is the Error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.grad.project.security.security.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'com.grad.project.security.UserService' that could not be found.
Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.grad.project.security.UserService' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace ?

Comment: you can mock UserService to resolve the bean dependency error

Comment: @vaibhavsahu I've updated post with 'Caused by'.
I know, but does it affect test results somehow? And I also wonder if there is another way to solve this issue ( can I mock userService for all test classes instead of writing it for every class? )

Comment: Yes, you can Mock your UserService for all the tests. @Mock annotation will help you here.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Try using the [`@ContextConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) annotation.

Comment: Or skip the clever "slicing" business and just use `@SpringBootTest`.